# Mock interface properties using Moq

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IHealthHandler
{
    bool GetCurrentHealthStatus();
    void SetCurrentHealthStatus(bool status);
}
```

I'm trying to mock it in such a way that `GetCurrentHealthStatus` is `true`.

I thought this should have worked but it doesn't:

```
var mockIHealthHandler = new Mock<IHealthHandler>();
mockIHealthHandler.SetupProperty(x => x.GetCurrentHealthStatus(), true);
```

How is this done?

Comment: `GetCurrentHealthStatus` is not a property, is a method. Is there a reason why you are using Getters and Setters manually in C#, instead of declaring the property correctly using `bool CurrentHealthStatus { get; set; }` ?

Comment: Mostly because I'm brand new to C# and am very unfamiliar with it. If I have this in my class `public bool CurrentHealthStatus { get; set; }`, what should the interface look like? The same?

Comment: Yes, properties in C# are declared using the same syntax as shown in my previous comment. Then you may use `SetupProperty`. `Setup` (as shown in the answer) must be used only on methods. In your case you should really avoid those two methods and use properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

try this

```
mockIHealthHandler.Setup(x => x.GetCurrentHealthStatus()).Returns(true);
```